# Fixing if else if statements for java game

Tags: java, if-statement

```
String option = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
    "A wooden crate appears! It looks ready to kick your butt!",
    "Battle!",
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, 
    null, 
    attacks, 
    attacks[0]);
    if (option.equals("slash"))
    {
        damage = (int)(Math.random()*(stick.getMax()-stick.getMin()) + stick.getMin());
    }               
    else if (option.equals("magic"))
    {
        if (playerMana >= 25)
        { 
            damage = (int) intellect*((stick.getMax()-stick.getMin())/2) + (int)Math.round(Math.pow(playerLevel, 1.20));
            playerMana -= 25;
        }
        else
        {
            damage = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (option.equals("run"))
    {
        out.println("fail! you run from the fight!");
    }
    else if (option.equals("healing") && healPots >= 1)
    {
        playerHp+= (playerHp*0.15);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("you have no potions! Get some in town to heal your hp!");
    }
```

Stick is just a weapon object I made with min max damage values. Player hp and mana are both 100. healPots is 0.

I am trying to make a rpg style fighting system where the player picks options and takes turns. However, the loop automatically skips to the final else regardless of what is chosen.

Comment: Just a point of English usage -- if and else blocks are not "loops" since they don't in fact control a loop as for loops or while loops do. You can call them control blocks or something else, but you'll not want to call them loops. There, I'm done.

Comment: Just a recommendation : when comparing two objects and one of them is a constant, **always** put the constant first, and compare with it (example : "slash".equals(option)). Bye bye NPE in objects comparison ;)

Comment: As for your code, it looks quite flat with much cyclomatic complexity, and I would recommend a re-write using more OOPs -such as a Weapon class that Stick can inherit from, that is smart enough to know what kind of damage it can do, a Player class that perhaps can have subclasses for each different type of player type, that can use Weapons, that can inflict and receive damage. This could simplify your code, reducing its complexity and by reducing coupling.

Comment: I swapped the left and right sides of the .equals but it didn't help. Also, @above, I have a class called "Stick" that the "stick" is created from. And that class has fields to input min and max damage ranges.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of the variable `attacks`? Also, what happens if you insert the line `System.out.println(option);` above the first `if`? Does it print what you think it should print?

Comment: String[] attacks = {"slash!", "magic!", "healing!", "run!"}; Yes it prints what is expected.

Comment: See my updated answer, I found your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you ask a question on SO, it is always a good idea to provide a minimal, running example.

I removed the actual game logic from your code and replaced `frame` with `null`:

```
public class ShubhankarsQuestion
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] attacks = {"slash", "magic", "run", "healing"};

        String option = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                "A wooden crate appears! It looks ready to kick your butt!",
                "Battle!", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null, attacks, attacks[0]);

        if (option.equals("slash"))
        {
            System.out.println("You chose slash...");
        }
        else if (option.equals("magic"))
        {
            System.out.println("You chose magic...");
        }
        else if (option.equals("run"))
        {
            System.out.println("You chose run...");
        }
        else if (option.equals("healing"))
        {
            System.out.println("You chose healing...");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("you have no potions! Get some in town to heal your hp!");
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly. Either you haven't shown us the actual code, or your problem lies elsewhere.

> Can you show us the definition of the variable attacks?
>
> ```
> String[] attacks = {"slash!", "magic!", "healing!", "run!"};
> ```

Well, there you have it. You compare `"slash!"` with `"slash"`, which certainly isn't equal :)

Either remove the exclamation marks from the array, or add them to the compared strings.

Comment: okay thanks! By the way Im a novice at this and I started without any prior planning. I find myself making one small change that results in me editing everything! Is there a more efficient setup? how many classes should I use to prevent this?

Comment: `"Well, there you have it. You compare "slash!" with "slash", which certainly isn't equal"` -- nice eyes. 1+

Comment: @ShubhankarDas: one way to avoid this error is to use String constants. Better to not use Strings at all.

Comment: @ShubhankarDas It's impossible to answer design questions in a comment. You could ask on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) of find a private tutor.